# Rails: Place all models in one file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-models

Hey so I realize this probably isn't good practice, but I was wondering if it's technically possible to combine the code from my various rails model files into one .rb file?

I have a lot of very short models, and when making changes to them it'd be quite helpful to be able to see them all in one place instead of having to open up numerous windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This goes against the rails philosophy of Convention over Configuration.

Ruby is a highly flexible language, so yes it would be possible to do that, but you would have to undo much of the auto-configuration that makes up the entire reason for using rails.